# Select only one checkbox in as3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have about 18 checkboxes and I would want to 
know if there is a way how i can make only one of them be 
choosen. I.e I can't choose 2 of the boxes an error will occure.
I know I could do it with radioboxes but for estetic I prefere checkboxes.
Could you provide me with some code please

Comment: Skin a radiobutton as a checkbox..thats way easier

Answer (score 0):

Try somethiung like this

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        [Bindable]
        private var selectedCheckBox:String = "";
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:CheckBox id="checkBox1" label="CheckBox" click="selectedCheckBox = checkBox1.id"
            selected="{selectedCheckBox == checkBox1.id}"/>
<s:CheckBox id="checkBox2" label="CheckBox" click="selectedCheckBox = checkBox2.id"
            selected="{selectedCheckBox == checkBox2.id}"/>
<s:CheckBox id="checkBox3" label="CheckBox" click="selectedCheckBox = checkBox3.id"
            selected="{selectedCheckBox == checkBox3.id}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to use Radio button which is skinned as check-box to match the aesthetics you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
private var selectedCB : CheckBox;

for( var i : int = 0, n : int = 18; i < n ; i++ ){
    var cb : CheckBox = new CheckBox();
    cb.addEventListener( Event.CHANGE, onChangeEvent_checkBox );
    //position cb etc.
    this.addChild( cb );
}

private function onChangeEvent_checkBox( event : Event ) :void{
    var currentCB : CheckBox = CheckBox( event.target );
    if( selectedCB && currentCB !== selectedCB )
        selectedCB.deselect();
    selectedCB = ( currentCB.selected ) ? currentCB : null;

}
```

But, TBH I think this is a bad idea. Users know how radiobuttons and checkboxes should behave and IMO it's VERY bad idea (from a UX POV) to start mixing those. Granted, this isn't exactly how radiobuttons behave, but close enough to be confusing.